# Python RegEx extract text between two patterns

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to pull out values for lat and lng for the following:

```
coordinates = 
[<div class="store-map">\n<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>\n<script>\r\n                function initMap() {\r\n                    var myLatLng = {\r\n                        lat: 42.050994,\r\n                        lng: -88.077711                    };\r\n\r\n
```

However, when I apply this regex -

```
found = re.search('lat:(.*),', coordinates,).group(1)
```

Everything after "lat:" is returned.
However, the desired result is just the number, that stops as soon as it reaches the comma.
This is odd to me, because even [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/griUzp6hvK) shows that code should work.
Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong here?

P.S.  I have spent a bit of time, and looked at all related solutions on stackoverflow, however - no dice.

Comment: Can you share for what example of latitude it's failing?

Comment: Just use `r'lat:(\d[\d.]*)'`

Comment: Hi  ShreyasG, example is defined as coordinates =  at the beginning of the post.   But it looks like Roman has a working solution already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way with `re.findall` function:

```
import re

coordinates = '[<div class="store-map">\n<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>\n<script>\r\n                function initMap() {\r\n                    var myLatLng = {\r\n                        lat: 42.050994,\r\n                        lng: -88.077711                    };\r\n\r\n '
result = re.findall(r'\b(?:lat|lng): -?\d+\.\d+', coordinates)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['lat: 42.050994', 'lng: -88.077711']
```

Comment: Note there is no need in the outer capturing group. If there is no capturing group in a pattern, `re.findall` return a list with match values only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, sure, that was unintentionally, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to extract the two values:

```
import re

text = """[<div class="store-map">\n<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>\n<script>\r\n                function initMap() {\r\n                    var myLatLng = {\r\n                        lat: 42.050994,\r\n                        lng: -88.077711                    };\r\n\r\n     """

lat, lng = map(float, re.findall(r'(?:lat|lng):\s+([0-9.-]*?)[, ]', text))
print lat, lng
```

Giving you two floats as:

```
42.050994 -88.077711
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `.*` is greedy meaning it would match everything up to the *last* comma. Change it to `.*?`:

```
lat:(.*?),
       ^
   add this
```